# Xamarin issue initialising HttpClient

Tags: c#, xamarin, httpclient

I have an issue with my Android project in Xamarin when running debugging that has just started occurring. It's just about the first thing that happens after `InitializeComponent();` in `App.xaml.cs`.
I'm initialising HttpClient as follows:

```
static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

but straight away get the following error message:

```
{System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in ObjCRuntime.RuntimeOptions:GetHttpMessageHandler (): IL_0000: ret
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.CreateDefaultHandler () [0x00000] in <e329308c7a294b1ebc65b0effd900db2>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient..ctor () [0x00000] in <e329308c7a294b1ebc65b0effd900db2>:0 
  at [MYAPP].Web.WebClient..cctor () [0x00000] in [MYAPPPATH]\Web\WebClient.cs:20 }
```

I can't seem to find any help and support out there so any help much appreciated.

Cheers,

Justin

Comment: You may have error in your app settings.  See : https://xamarin.github.io/bugzilla-archives/41/41240/bug.html

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm with 99% certainty that it's related to the latest updates of Visual Studio 2019 Community (not sure if this is isolated to just Community).  I had this exact same issue when I updated from 16.8.x to 16.9.2 and can confirm that it is still present in 16.9.3.  I've got a separate laptop with VS 2019 16.7.6 running the same codebase without issue.

Unfortunately it appears that there is no way to rollback VS 2019 Community installs.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Many thanks, it turned out that Xamarin.iOS had found its way into my Android project cauing the issue.

Comment: Wow.  This is exactly what happened with me as well.  Removing the Xam.iOS references from BOTH the .Android and .iOS projects fixed the issue for me.  I appreciate the help!  It's a mystery how the references got there in the first place... Oh well.